# Particular crontab not working on centos 6.2

Tags: centos, cron

I have 3 cronjob set to work on reboot. When I reboot only 2 works and the 3rd one does not work. What could be stopping it from working? Where to get the clues? All of it I have redirection for the output done and there is a .log file generated for all 3. But the problematic cron job have empty log file.

EDIT From /var/log/cron

> Jul 19 01:06:08 itest CROND[2155]: (root) CMD (/home/test1/PF_RING-5.4.3/userland/examples/packetSecondAnalyis.c -m 2>&1 >> /var/log/myPacketeSecondAnalyis.log)
>
> Jul 19 01:06:08 itest CROND[2154]: (root) CMD (/home/test1/PF_RING-5.4.3/userland/examples/pfExeV3.c -m 2>&1 >> /var/log/myPacketCapture.log)
>
> Jul 19 01:06:08 itest CROND[2156]: (root) CMD (/home/test1/PF_RING-5.4.3/userland/examples/pAR.c -m 2>&1 >> /var/log/myPAR.log)

Issue now is crond[2156] is not running. I have checked using top command also not there?

Comment: Take a second to re-read this question, please. There are *no* meaningful details, how could anyone here possibly answer this? Take a read of [ask] and edit this to have more information please. A good start would be the contents of your crontab.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `/var/log/cron` for interesting messages.

When you do `>>` you are only redirecting stdout you may need to catch stderr too e.g.

```
@reboot root  somecommand &>/tmp/logfile.log
```

Edit: you have the syntax for your redirect wrong try

```
@reboot root /home/test1/PF_RING-5.4.3/userland/examples/pAR.c -m >> /var/log/myPAR.log 2>&1
```

or

```
@reboot root /home/test1/PF_RING-5.4.3/userland/examples/pAR.c -m &> /var/log/myPAR.log
```

Comment: should I change my crontab line to @reboot root  somecommand &>/tmp/logfile.log this is it?

Comment: I have checked /var/log/cron no error is just showing this Jul 19 01:06:08 itest CROND[2155]: (root) CMD (/home/test1/PF_RING-5.4.3/userland/examples/packetSecondAnalyis.c -m 2>&1 >> /var/log/myPacketeSecondAnalyis.log)
Jul 19 01:06:08 itest CROND[2154]: (root) CMD (/home/test1/PF_RING-5.4.3/userland/examples/pfExeV3.c -m 2>&1 >> /var/log/myPacketCapture.log)
Jul 19 01:06:08 itest CROND[2156]: (root) CMD (/home/test1/PF_RING-5.4.3/userland/examples/pAR.c -m 2>&1 >> /var/log/myPAR.log)
Issue now is crond[2156] is not running. I have checked using top command also not there?

Comment: @newbie14: see my edit

Comment: Both gives me this /bin/sh: root: command not found. I have checked the file is own by root.

Comment: @newbie14: If you're running the command from root's crontab then remove the `root` - I kind of assumed you were running it from `/etc/crontab`

Comment: @lain I have removed and tried both method nothing change.